# How to find a context of paragraph, with a help of a BERT?

Tags: nlp

I'm looking for a way to run a simple example with BERT.
How to analyse context with google BERT? https://github.com/google-research/bert
For example, i have a paragraph of a wikipedia text, and pre-trained BERT model from google. How to pass paragraph to BERT and get a text representation of main context?
Thanks!

EDTED:

Example: we have paragraph

"I'm looking for a way to run a simple example with BERT. How to analyse context with google BERT? https://github.com/google-research/bert For example, i have a paragraph of a wikipedia text, and pre-trained BERT model from google. How to pass paragraph to BERT and get a text representation of main context? Thanks!"

The context should be "How to analyse context with google BERT?" or "How to analyze"

The problem for me is to figure out how to teach model to pick up main sentence from other ones. ^example above.

The other problem: how to work with documents larger than 512 tokens?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume, it should be possible without fine tuning and training, because pre-trained model allready learned on wikipedia data. If im wrong, im kindly appreciated for guidance how to achieve wikipedia paragraph context analysis.

Comment: The phrase - "text representation of main context" - is not clear. Please post example input and output to help understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks man! Edited with example.

Comment: Hi @OlexanderKorenyuk . did you find any suitable model for this task? what did yoou use?

Comment: @whoosis after eons of rnd i came out with my own model. It worked so well so i decided to commercialise it https://www.qubitgrid.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have already trained it on SQuAD dataset for question answering task which is a sequence to sequence task like yours. So, you can just fine-tune it with a proper dataset (text summarization perhaps).